# How do I correct the error: RUNTIME ERROR: Compilation error on line 4. Index out of range taking subset of y

Tags: r, linear-regression, bayesian, jags, rjags

I've built a linear regression model using `rjags` but I am getting a runtime error saying the index is out of range. I've looked for advice online but can't find anything that I understand or addresses this exact problem.

Here is my code:

```
modelstring1= "
model{
  for (i in 1:n) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], prec)
    mu[i] = b[1] + b[2]*lnimi[i]
  }
  
  for (j in 1:2) {
    b[j] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1.0E6)
  }
  
  prec ~ dgamma(20.0/2, 20.0*10.0/2)
  sig2 = 1.0 / prec
  sig = sqrt(sig2)
}"


jags_data1 = list(y=Reisby["hd"], n=nrow(Reisby))

params1 = c("b", "sig")

inits1 = function() {
  inits = list("b"=rnorm(2.0, 0.0, 100.0), "prec"=rgamma(1, 1.0, 1.0))
}

model1 = jags.model(textConnection(modelstring1), data=jags_data1, inits = inits1)
```

And the error is:

> Compiling model graph
> Resolving undeclared variables
> Deleting model
> Error in jags.model(textConnection(modelstring1), data = jags_data1, inits = inits1) :
> RUNTIME ERROR:
> Compilation error on line 4.
> Index out of range taking subset of  y

The closest advice I've seen says that the mu range is too small but I don't really understand how that is the problem here.
Unsure if the `"lnimi"` field in the `Reisby` data needs to be specified anywhere as it is included in the mu[I] statement?

Comment: you need to include `lnimi` in the data that you pass to `rjags`

Comment: also think that `Reisby["hd"]` would need to be `Reisby[,"hd"]` or `Reisby$hd` e.g. a vector or matrix should be passed not a data frame

Comment: I've tried putting: 
jags_data1 = list(y=Reisby_df$hd, x=Reisby_df$lnimi, n=length(Reisby))
but I still get the same error, am I trying to add the data incorrectly? I've also tried lnimi=Reisby_df$lnimi as I was following a tutorial on YouTube but still get this error. I've changed my data source from Reisby which wasn't a dataframe to Reisby_df which is, and I'm still it hasn't made a difference. Sorry I'm sure this is basic but I'm just lost.

Comment: you don't have an `x` in your model. You have `lnimi`. So either change the relevant line to `mu[i] = b[1] + b[2]*x[i]` which will match the data in your comment above or else change the data to `list(y=Reisby_df$hd, lnimi=Reisby_df$lnimi, n=nrow(Reisby_df))` (use `nrow` not `length`)

Comment: If this doesn't work can you edit your question with the results of `dput(head(Reisby_df))` thanks

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to all of the people who commented, I've now got a working model! The final code is:

```
 modelstring1= "
model{
  for (i in 1:n) {
    y[i] ~ dnorm(mu[i], prec)
    mu[i] = b[1] + b[2]*lnimi[i]
  }
  
  for (j in 1:2) {
    b[j] ~ dnorm(0.0, 1.0/1.0E6)
  }
  
  prec ~ dgamma(20.0/2, 20.0*10.0/2)
  sig2 = 1.0 / prec
  sig = sqrt(sig2)
}"


jags_data1 = list(y=Reisby_df$hd, lnimi=Reisby_df$lnimi, n=nrow(Reisby))


model1 = jags.model(textConnection(modelstring1), data=jags_data1, inits = inits1, n.chains = 2)
```